# Dynamic create elements in vueJS list

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a litte list which works just fine in vueJS:

```
<ul id="pieces">
<li v-for="stuff in pieces">
    <label>
    <span></span>
    <input
        v-model="checkedpieces"
        v-on:change="toggleStuff"
        type="checkbox"/>
    </label>
</li>
```

Additionally I want to load list elements in that list dynamically and since it could a be large number, can't use v-if or so.

I believe that I should use Vue.extend and copying the html into a template:

```
var customPiece = Vue.extend({

    template: '<li class="Piece" cod-unidad="'+assetCodigoUnidad+'"         nombre_cliente="'+assetNombreCliente+'"/>'+
            '<label>'+assetNombreUnidad+
            '<span class="piecesAssetsGroup piecesAssetsClientRed">'+assetNombreCliente+'</span>'+
            '<input type="checkbox" value="'+assetCodigoUnidad+'-'+assetNombreCliente+'" cod-unidad="'+assetCodigoUnidad+'" nombre_cliente="'+assetNombreCliente+'" v-on:change="togglePiece">'+
            '</label>'+
            '</li>',

var v_customPiece = new customPiece().$mount();
$('#pieces').append(v_customPiece.$el);
```

And it works, but when I try to fire the **v-on** trigger, it fails becouse the scope changed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: your title is confusing is it dynamic or dinamic?

Comment: I mean dynamic, sorry.

Comment: I think you should be able to use v-if for a large list. Using a component for each would be more limiting. It should also be noted that in your first code example, each of the checkboxes will be modifying the same variable 'checkedpieces'. A better approach would be to do something like v-model='stuff.checked'.